# Detect if external call takes to long time in Python

Tags: python, timer, subprocess, external, popen

In my Python script I make an external call using subprocess.Popen(). If the call hasn't returned within x seconds I need to send an email indicating that something is wrong. How can I put a time limit on the execution of the external call? Note that I am not interested in terminating the call, just detecting that it takes too long.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the subprocess object's `poll` is for.  See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll

You can use `time.sleep()` to wait for the timeout interval.  Then `poll` the subprocess object to see if it's done.

If it's done, that's good.

If it's not done, your app sends an email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals for that:

```
 signal.alarm(time)
```

from http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

taken from the python docs:

```
  import signal, os

  def handler(signum, frame):
     print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
     raise IOError("Couldn't open device!")

  # Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
  signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
  signal.alarm(5)

  # This open() may hang indefinitely
  fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

  signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use sleep and check if the subprocess is alive like this :

from multiprocessing import Process

```
checker = Process(target=yourFunction, args=(some_queue))
timeout = 150
checker.start()
counter = 0
while checker.is_alive() == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        if counter > timeout :
                print "Child process consumed too much run-time."
                break
```